# Warning: Illegal offset type (multiple) when creating new report from template (D8/Civi5.11)

Tags: reports, drupal-8

I'm using Drupal 8 / Civi 5.11

I get the following errors on the screen multiple times (one for each Drupal role in my system) when I attempt to create a new report in CiviCRM (CiviCRM->Admin->CiviReports->Create New Report From Template -- using Constituent Summary, for example):

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in CRM_Report_Form_Instance::buildForm() (line 135 of /var/www/site/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Report/Form/Instance.php).
```

It appears that on line 135, the Drupal roles are being iterated and assumed to be strings.  They are, in fact, objects in Drupal 8.

Does anyone know if this is a bug already reported/being work on?  I've looked at the issue queue but haven't turned anything up.

Is my system, perhaps, just misconfigured and it's not a bug after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in CiviCRM and is not handled properly for D8, you can fix this by applying below patch

```
diff --git a/CRM/Report/Form/Instance.php b/CRM/Report/Form/Instance.php
index 8f00408a17..965949e21c 100644
--- a/CRM/Report/Form/Instance.php
+++ b/CRM/Report/Form/Instance.php
@@ -112,7 +112,13 @@ class CRM_Report_Form_Instance {
     if (function_exists('user_roles')) {
       $user_roles_array = user_roles();
       foreach ($user_roles_array as $key => $value) {
-        $user_roles[$value] = $value;
+        if (is_object($value) && is_a($value, 'Drupal\user\Entity\Role')) {
+          $value = $value->label();
+        }
+        else {
+          $key = $value;
+        }
+        $user_roles[$key] = $value;
       }
       $grouprole = $form->addElement('advmultiselect',
         'grouprole',
```

Comment: There is an official patch recently committed. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15318/files and you'll also need https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16273 for it to enforce access.